# Setting "if one column has value, other must be null" constraint on columns using ModelBuilder (Fluent API)

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework-core, constraints

```
public class Owner 
{
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public int? CarId { get; set; }
   public int? BoatId { get; set; }
}
```

Given the `Owner` class shown here, is it possible to define a constraint such that each row can only have one `CarId` or one `BoatId` or both be null?

| Id | CarId | BoatId | Outcome |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | null | null | OK |
| 1 | 10 | null | OK |
| 2 | null | 20 | OK |
| 3 | 30 | 40 | Error |

Can I set such a constraint using fluent api?

```
  modelBuilder.Entity<Owner>()
              ...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Owner>().HasCheckConstraint("ckOwner_CarOrBoatOrNeither", $"CarId is null or BoatId is null");
```

[Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.relationalentitytypebuilderextensions.hascheckconstraint?view=efcore-5.0)

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone stumbles upon this looking for the opposite (NOT NULL when other column is NOT NULL but NULL when other column is NULL) I used the marked answer here with a couple tweaks.

I'm also using `IEntityTypeConfiguration`

```
  builder.HasCheckConstraint(
            "ckTableName_XNotNullWhenYNotNull", 
            $"(X is NOT null AND Y is NOT null) OR (X is null AND Y is null)");
```

Don't know if that will help anyone but just something I was struggling to find by Googling.